# Where to apply firebase onAuthStateChanged

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I have this very basic sample code, consisting of SignIn, SignUp, Home & Profile screens along with a Loading screen and some stack & tab navigators.

I am trying to incorporate firebase into this code so that when app loads it checks if user is not authenticated then it goes to AuthStack elseif user is authenticated then it goes to AppStack.

The problem I am facing is that the application is stuck at Loading screen and the code inside componentDidMount does not seems to be working.

I took reference from the following [**link**](https://medium.com/react-native-training/react-native-firebase-authentication-7652e1d2c8a2) and the only change I made was putting SignIn and SignUp in a TabNavigator rather than having them individually as mentioned in the article.

Can someone please suggest what is it that is wrong with my code.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  SafeAreaView,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  ScrollView,
} from 'react-native';

import {
  createAppContainer,
  createSwitchNavigator,
  createStackNavigator,
  createMaterialTopTabNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation';

import * as firebase from 'firebase';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyCCJSgB3gS5SMqa2aUap8kYkE2ZhtN3tn4",
  authDomain: "fire8266-test.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://fire8266-test.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "",
};

const colors = {
  primary: '#FF1493',
  secondary: '#b9b9b9'
}

const fonts = {
  hairline: 'Lato-Hairline',
  light: 'Lato-Light',
  base: 'Lato-Regular',
  bold: 'Lato-Bold'
}

class LoadingScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    if (!firebase.apps.length) {
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    }
  }
  componentDidMount = async () => {
    this.authSubscription = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      this.props.navigation.navigate(user ? 'App' : 'Auth');
    });
  };

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.authSubscription();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Loading...</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class SignInScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Sign In...</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class ForgetPasswordScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Forget Password...</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class SignUpScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Sign Up...</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Home...</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class ProfileScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Profile...</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const SignInStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    SignIn: {
      screen: SignInScreen,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        header: null,
      }),
    },
    ForgetPassword: {
      screen: ForgetPasswordScreen,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: 'Forget Password',
      }),
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'SignIn',
    headerMode: 'screen',
  }
);

const SignUpStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    SignUp: {
      screen: SignUpScreen,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'SignUp',
    headerMode: 'none',
  }
);

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    headerMode: 'none',
  }
);

const ProfileStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Profile: {
      screen: ProfileScreen,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Profile',
    headerMode: 'none',
  }
);

const LoadingStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Loading: {
      screen: LoadingScreen,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        header: null,
      }),
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Loading',
    headerMode: 'screen',
  }
);

const AuthStack = createAppContainer(
  createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
    {
      SignIn: {
        screen: SignInStack,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
          title: 'Sign In',
        }),
      },
      SignUp: {
        screen: SignUpStack,
        navigationOptions: () => ({
          title: 'Sign Up',
        }),
      },
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'SignIn',
      tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
      swipeEnabled: true,
      animationEnabled: true,
    }
  )
);

const AppStack = createAppContainer(
  createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
    {
      Home: {
        screen: HomeStack,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
          title: 'Home',
        }),
      },
      Profile: {
        screen: ProfileStack,
        navigationOptions: () => ({
          title: 'Profile',
        }),
      },
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'Home',
      tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
      swipeEnabled: true,
      animationEnabled: true,
    }
  )
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      Loading: LoadingStack,
      App: AppStack,
      Auth: AuthStack,
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'Loading',
    }
  )
);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <AppContainer />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
  icon: {
    width: 26,
    height: 26,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

well i think i solved the problem by wrapping the TabNavigators in StackNavigator.

```
const AuthStack = createAppContainer(
  createStackNavigator(
    {
      Auth: createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
        {
          SignIn: {
            screen: SignInStack,
            navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
              title: 'Sign In',
            }),
          },
          SignUp: {
            screen: SignUpStack,
            navigationOptions: () => ({
              title: 'Sign Up',
            }),
          },
        },
        {
          initialRouteName: 'SignIn',
          tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
          swipeEnabled: true,
          animationEnabled: true,
        }
      ),
    },
    {
      headerMode: 'modal',
      header: null
    }
  )
);

const AppStack = createAppContainer(
  createStackNavigator(
    {
      App: createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
        {
          Home: {
            screen: HomeStack,
            navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
              title: 'Home',
            }),
          },
          Profile: {
            screen: ProfileStack,
            navigationOptions: () => ({
              title: 'Profile',
            }),
          },
        },
        {
          initialRouteName: 'Home',
          tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
          swipeEnabled: true,
          animationEnabled: true,
        }
      ),
    },
    {
      headerMode: 'modal',
      header: null
    }
  )
);
```